# Php choosing a random colour for each word in an array

Tags: php, arrays, colors

I am making a website for a friend and he wants it to be creative/colourful. I would like to have a sentence on the page that has a lot of words, if I have all of those words in an array and have a foreach echoing each of the words, how could I select a random colour from another array and have the colour of the text set. I have tried the following code, but it doesn't work:

```
<?php
$array = array('lots','of','random','words','here');
$colours = array(0=>'green',1=>'red',2=>'blue',3=>'orange',4=>'purple',5=>'pink',6=>'yellow');
foreach ($array as $words) {
    $rand = rand(0,6);
    echo "<div style='display: inline-block;font-colour: ".$colours[$rand]."'>",$words,'</div> ';
}
?>
```

Anyone know how this can be accomplished?

Comment: maybe try just `color` instead of `font-colour` ?

Comment: tried that, no difference

Comment: you forgot semicolon after color: ".$colours[$rand]."

Answer (score 0):

Ok so I managed to solve it, if anyone wants to know what I did here's the code

```
<?php
$title = '';
$array = array('lots','of','random','words','here');
$colours = array(1=>'#226fbe', 2=>'#ff0000', 3=>'#22be52', 4=>'#eb9713', 5=>'#eb13de', 6=>'#ebd413');
foreach ($array as $words) {
    $rand = array_rand($colours);
    $title .= '<div class="title" style="color:'.$colours[$rand].'">'.$words.'</div> ';
    global $title;
}
echo $title;
?>
```